# Batch file: Need to search for and copy files from an input list

Tags: loops, batch-file, dos, batch-processing

I'm not very good with programming anything, even batch files.

I've created a batch file that will copy files from a big folder full of images, based on the number I input. However, I'd like to be able to insert a list of numbers (separated by spaces, commas, or whatever) and have it loop through my 2 xcopy commands for each number.

Here's what I've got so far. It only works for one number at a time, of course:

```
@echo off
set SourceFolder=\\1.2.3.4\ImagePool
set TargetFolder=C:\Users\BevansDesign\Desktop\ProductFiles
set /p SKUList=SKU Numbers:
echo RUNNING...
xcopy /s %SourceFolder%\%SKUList%.* %TargetFolder%\
echo STILL RUNNING...
xcopy /s %SourceFolder%\%SKUList%_*.* %TargetFolder%\
echo COMPLETE.
pause
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I tried googling, but most of what I found was confusing and scary.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
@echo off
set SourceFolder=\\1.2.3.4\ImagePool
set TargetFolder=C:\Users\BevansDesign\Desktop\ProductFiles
set /p SKUList=SKU Numbers:
echo RUNNING...
for %%i in (%SKUList%) do (
    xcopy /s %SourceFolder%\%%i.* %TargetFolder%\
    echo STILL RUNNING...
    xcopy /s %SourceFolder%\%%i_*.* %TargetFolder%\
)
echo COMPLETE.
pause
```

enter the list as either numbers seperated by commas, or numbers seperated by spaces, and please remember, i havent had a chance to test this yet. the for just itterates through the input and takes every number and executes the code in the parens on that number.